# How this below R code equivalent to Julia code?

Tags: r, dataframe, julia, subset

[image]

I am trying some julia code as shown here:

[image]

However, I get an error:

[image]

Comment: Rather than posting pictures of code and output, please copy and paste it into your post, making sure to use proper formatting. Reading pictures is hard, and copying and testing your code is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In Julia `1` and `1.0` are different. `1` is an `Integer` while `1.0` is a floating point number. R only has floating point numbers. you want `x` and `y` to be Integers.

Comment: R does have integers but different input rules/less fussy: `identical(1, 1.0)` is TRUE; `identical(1L, 1)` is FALSE; `1.0 == 1L` is TRUE. R also allows indexing by floating-point values, it (inadvisable) coerces them to integer; `c(1,2)[1.1]`

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using incorrectly the filtering.
Suppose you have a data frame:

```
data = DataFrame(a=1:6, b='a':'f');
```

One way to filter would be to use a `BitVector` such as:

```
julia> rows = data.a .< 3
6-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0

julia> data[rows, :]
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Char
─────┼─────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │     2  b
```

You could of course just write `data[data.a .< 3, :]`

If you want to use `filter` instead the code could look like this:

```
julia> filter(row -> row.a  < 3, data)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Char
─────┼─────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │     2  b
```